# How to change my python version in AWS elastic-beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I am working with nodejs in my elastic-beanstalk with python 2

How can I change to python3

I did python installation in cli and

> sudo alternatives --config python

to change my python to 3 but the system crashed.

How can I achieve this.

I need to setup a nodejs environment with python3 in elastic-beanstalk. right now its with python2.

Comment: I don't know how it will work for python, but for me it worked for ruby. I upgraded 2.2 to 2.4. You need to save a config of env to file, edit it (change python version to 3.x and AMI_ID). This file can be found in S3 for appropriate env. Then load a patched configuration. New AMI_ID and Python name can be found when  you start creating new ENV for python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to build a new environment and afterwards swap environment urls

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html

This requires that your database is independent of your current environment.

Comment: if I set python3 the AWS log building, bundle building etc fails, Even if i Swap this is going to happen with new env. the entire AWS env crashes.

Comment: your descriptions are verry imprecise. It is unclear which steps you do and how to reproduce. Make a list of steps when you build a new env. And show us the errors. Otherwise no one can help you.